# ASPX throws "404 The resource cannot be found"

Tags: iis, iis-6, asp.net, http-status-code-404

I'm deploying a website under a virtual directory using IIS. For some strange reason, Default.html works, but Default.aspx throws a 404.

I have tried these:

- There's another virtual directory that contains an older version of the application and that one just works. I checked the properties of each virtual directory and they looked the same.
- I checked that the root [didn't had any extra backslashes](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t96894-the-resource-cannot-be-found-error-accessing-a-aspx-file.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the tool: aspnet_regiis.exe to reinstall script maps for IIS. Remember to completly reset IIS by using command: iisreset.

Document here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A 404 error will be thrown for any file extension that is not registered with a MIME type (ie: data) or a server side handler (ie: code). Try running `aspnet_regiis.exe -i -enable` to make sure that ASP.NET is registered with IIS and that it is enabled as a web extension.