# IIS ASPX 404 Errors on Windows Server 2008

Tags: iis, asp.net

IIS has been giving HTTP 404 errors for ASPX files. I've got the proper handlers registered with ISAPI, but the other article [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/96713/aspx-throws-404-the-resource-cannot-be-found) suggested running the command:

```
aspnet_regiis -i
```

That didn't work either and IIS is still giving 404 errors.

Comment: Looks like some of your question got lost or deleted - please edit the part which currently says "giving HTTP 404 errors for AI've..." to include the problem details.